# Can't I set the number with a decimal part to "MinMoneyValidator()" and "MaxMoneyValidator()" in "MoneyField()" with Django-money?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-money

I use [Django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money), then I set `0.00` and `999.99` to `MinMoneyValidator()` and `MaxMoneyValidator()` respectively in `MoneyField()` as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from djmoney.models.validators import MinMoneyValidator, MaxMoneyValidator 

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = MoneyField( # Here
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[        # Here                    # Here
            MinMoneyValidator(0.00), MaxMoneyValidator(999.99),
        ]
    )
```

Then, I tried to add a product as shown below:

[image]

But, I got the error below:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

So, I set `0` and `999` to `MinMoneyValidator()` and `MaxMoneyValidator()` respectively in `MoneyField()` as shown below, then the error above was solved:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from djmoney.models.fields import MoneyField
from djmoney.models.validators import MinMoneyValidator, MaxMoneyValidator

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = MoneyField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[       # Here                 # Here
            MinMoneyValidator(0), MaxMoneyValidator(999),
        ]
    )
```

Actually, I can set `0.00` and `999.99` to [MinValueValidator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) and [MaxValueValidator()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator) respectively in [models.DecimalField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) without any errors as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator 

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField( # Here
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0,
        validators=[        # Here                    # Here
            MinValueValidator(0.00), MaxValueValidator(999.99)
        ],
    )
```

So, can't I set the number with the decimal part to `MinMoneyValidator()` and `MaxMoneyValidator()` in `MoneyField()`?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use [Decimal()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects):

```py
from decimal import Decimal


class Product(models.Model):
    # ...
    price = MoneyField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0, default_currency='USD',
        validators=[          # Here                            # Here
            MinMoneyValidator(Decimal(0.00)), MaxMoneyValidator(Decimal(999.99)),
        ]
    )
```